# How to use Task Factory Approach with a Button

Tags: java, cytoscape

I am developing an app on Cytoscape which is a data visualization program. I need to do certain thing when i clicked a button with using task factory. I implemented my task factory and task classes. I registered it in the actionperformed part but it did not worked. When i run the code on console there were no error messages.

How can i register task factory to a button?

Here is the part of my code which is related with this:

In MyControlPanel class:

```
this.provoImportButton.setText("Import");
    this.provoImportButton.setVerticalAlignment(1);
    this.provoImportButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            provoImportCore.importFile();
        }
    });
```

In provoImportCore class:

```
public void importFile(){
    String path = getWholePath();
    ExtractEdgesNodesTaskFactory extractEdgesNodesTaskFactory = new ExtractEdgesNodesTaskFactory(adapter,path);
    adapter.getCyServiceRegistrar().registerService(extractEdgesNodesTaskFactory,TaskFactory.class,new Properties());
}
```

ExtractEdgesNodesTaskFactory class:

```
public class ExtractEdgesNodesTaskFactory extends AbstractTaskFactory {

private CySwingAppAdapter adapter;
private String path;

public ExtractEdgesNodesTaskFactory(CySwingAppAdapter adapter, String path) {
    this.path = path;
    this.adapter = adapter;
}

public TaskIterator createTaskIterator() {
    return new TaskIterator(new ExtractEdgesNodesTask(adapter,path));
}
```

}

ExtractEdgesNodesTask class:

```
public class ExtractEdgesNodesTask extends AbstractTask{
private CySwingAppAdapter adapter;
private String path;

public ExtractEdgesNodesTask(CySwingAppAdapter adapter, String path){
    super();
    this.path =path;
    this.adapter = adapter;
}

public void run(TaskMonitor taskMonitor) {
    taskMonitor.setStatusMessage("Extracting Edges and Nodes ...");
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path);
    } catch (Exception es) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this.adapter.getCySwingApplication().getJFrame(),
                "The file that you choosed are not valid."  ,
                "Error!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        es.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}

public String getPath() {
    return path;
}

public void setPath(String path) {
    this.path = path;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

This was answered in detail on the cytoscape-app-dev list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cytoscape-app-dev/ZfP-GyeE7Dc